# how to specify both /clr and /mtd options for visualstudio c++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

in my project i have enabled [/clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(VS.80).aspx) (Common Language Runtime) support as well as /[MTd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(VS.80).aspx) (Multithreded Debug) option in code generation section.

But the compiler shows /clr and /MTd are incompatable types. I need to use both.
How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no /mtb i'm assuming /mtd

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is /clr incompatible with /mt and /mtd in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938539/why-is-clr-incompatible-with-mt-and-mtd-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can not use both optionsin a project because c/clr needs switches for that it must use

dynamic libraries instead of static.if u use /mtd it uses static libraries.so u can not '

use /clr and /mtd

Answer (score 4):

use the [/MDd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(VS.80).aspx) option instead, which is compatible with the /clr